# Display Actual Number Notification Dot Non Samsung Devices

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo

So on Samsung phones running Oreo [active notifications](https://gadgetguideonline.com/s8/use-notification-dots-notification-number-badge-in-galaxy-s8-android-oreo-update/) aka notification dots(on other devices) actually displays a number of the active notifications.

Is there a way to get the number(& not just the dot) to display on non Samsung Android Oreo devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some searching it appears Notifyer actually does work but there is a setting you have to change.  First create the widget of the application and put it on your desktop.  Next open the Notifyer app and go under settings for the specific application.

Lastly you must uncheck use native count.  If you would like you can also check group notifications.